# Alternate approach to limit evaluation

Tags: limits

Evaluate the $limit_{x \rightarrow \infty}$ {$2x$sin( $\frac{1}{x}$) - cos($\frac{1}{x}$) without using series expansion.

> My method was involving the series expansion which i was able to get the answer as $1$ after expanding sin(x) , and cosx ,replacing $x$ by $\frac{1}{x}$ we would finally get $limit_{x \rightarrow \infty}$ ($1+ \frac{1}{6x^2} -.....$higher order terms in denominator) But i would like to know if there is another approach without this .    Note : also i would like to know which indeterminate form is this limit type ? As such i am not able to see it as such

Comment: Replace 1/x as t ..where t tends to 0.and you will come across 0/0 indeterminate form..

Comment: Nice thanks got it